# printf working fine when kept outside of for loop but causes some error while running when kept in the for loop

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int b;
    printf("hello");
    for(b=1;b<=100;++b)
    {
        if(b%10==1){
          cout << "\n";
          for(int l=0;l<=100;++l)
            cout << "-" ;
            cout << endl;           
        }    
        printf("|%s|",b);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZmha.jpg)

printf which is placed outside of loop body works fine but the one placed in the loop body of for causes some kind of error while running!! take a look at the picture !

Comment: Check the spec for the meaning of `%s`. It does not fit your `int`.

Comment: What do you expect to see when you print an `int` as if it were a string, i.e. `printf("|%s|",b);`?

Comment: Your code is C++. No C compiler will accept it. You are aware of the difference, aren't you?

Comment: thanks Yunnosch! didnt see that! it worked !

Comment: `b` is an `int` and you'e using `%s` to print it. Btw, why not use `cout` like the rest to print `b` as well, considering you seem to be using C++?

Comment: how to close a question?

Comment: Closing is for off-topic, unclear or too broad questions and done by users with more privileges.

Comment: @JoSSte The error is shown. In the unloved shape of a picture, but it is there.

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks - i didn't notice the link was for an image while reveiwing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `b` is an `int`.
You give `b` where printf() expects a pointer to char and will attempt to dereference the value you give as such.
Since the value you give via `b` is not a valid pointer to anything, your program has some access problem.